# How to open .SQLite files

Tags: sqlite, file, spatialite

I'm trying to open a .sqlite file on Windows, but I don't know how to. Do you know a good program for it?

It contains data for statistical analysis, but I prefer having a .txt file.

I also have a .spatialite file. Can you help me?

Comment: such question should placed in Software Recommendation : http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ , StackOverFlow isn't the right place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using R and the package [RSQLite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html)

```
#install.packages("RSQLite") #perhaps needed
library("RSQLite")

# connect to the sqlite file
sqlite    <- dbDriver("SQLite")
exampledb <- dbConnect(sqlite,"database.sqlite")

dbListTables(exampledb)
```

Comment: I found this tutorial on RSQLite helpful: https://blog.exploratory.io/accessing-sqlite-with-rsqlite-and-querying-with-dplyr-in-r-script-7eecf1e1b5b0

Answer (score 122):

If you just want to see what's in the database without installing anything extra, you might already have SQLite CLI on your system. To check, open a command prompt and try:

```
sqlite3 database.sqlite
```

Replace `database.sqlite` with your database file. Then, if the database is small enough, you can view the entire contents with:

```
sqlite> .dump
```

Or you can list the tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
```

Regular SQL works here as well:

```
sqlite> select * from some_table;
```

Replace `some_table` as appropriate.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer, no need to install heavy weight packages

Comment: My Windows 10 did not recognize sqlite3 as a command.

Comment: @zylstra You'll have to install the sqlite cli first.

Comment: get it from here, use command prompt from the same folder you extracted it, https://sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3410200.zip

Comment: Or, for the latest, https://sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 80):

SQLite is database engine, `.sqlite` or `.db` should be a database. If you don't need to program anything, you can use a GUI like sqlitebrowser or anything like that to view the database contents.

- Website: http://sqlitebrowser.org/
- Project: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser

There is also spatialite, https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index

Comment: I think this is closer to the "right" answer.  I suspect a means to access the data via an API through `R` or another language is not as broadly helpful, even if it helped the OP.

Answer (score 51):

My favorite:

https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/

No installation needed. Just drop the file.

Comment: You are my life saver. thanks for your input.

Comment: This is so simple, and no callbacks to the server.  You can save the page for use offline if need be.